# iTerm2 adding extra characters when typing commands

Tags: macos, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I have a new installation of iTerm2 (3.4.3) with oh-my-zsh and the zsh-autosuggestions plugins installed. I noticed that whenever typing commands, extra characters are being added to the commands. This happens when typing normally and not when just pasting something.

I've attempted to add this to my .zshrc file and restarted the terminal window with no luck:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZZzs.png) is a screenshot of the behavior when I submit the command and then when I press the up key to load the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

In the terminal type `reset` and hit enter, that should fix it

**Long-term Solution**

To permanently disable bracketing paste mode:

Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Terminal Emulation >

[ ] "Terminal may enable paste bracketing"